# class cast exception: java.lang.String incompatible with [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, string, list, object, casting

What is wrong with below code ?

```
List<Object[]> currencies = null;
List<String> currencyList = new ArrayList<String>();

//code to fetch currency
String currencySql = "select C.Currency from Currency C";
Query currencyQuery = this.em.createQuery(currencySql);

currencies = currencyQuery.getResultList();

for (Object[] currency : currencies) {    //getting runtime error here
   for (int i = 0; i < currency.length; i++) {
            currencyList.add(currency[i].toString());
        }
    }
```

Getting runtime error in first line of for loop as: 
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String incompatible with [Ljava.lang.Object;

The code compiles alright.

What is the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are thinking that the Query would return a list of `Object` arrays.

The query will most likely return a list of `String`s (unless the Currency entity contains a Currency object, in which case I'd revisit the data design), so operating under the assumption that this is a scalar query, your code can be simplified to:

```
String currencySql = "select C.Currency from Currency C";
Query currencyQuery = this.em.createQuery(currencySql);

List<String> currencyList = (List<String>) currencyQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks!! So if the query is for several columns, in that case getResultList will return list of Object arrays. But in this case it was just one column, which was String, it returned a list of Strings. Correct ???

Comment: It depends on the concrete implementation of your EntityManager, but it certainly looks that way.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the debugger what is in currencies variable after

```
currencyQuery.getResultList();
```

Probably it is not a list of Object[], but a list of strings.

Comment: changing currencies to List<String[]> threw java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String incompatible with [Ljava.lang.String;

Comment: I mean not List<String[]>, but List<String>, because looks like your query returns one column, that is converted to list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `currencyList` should be of type `List` and not `List<Object[]>`. This also means that the `currency` variable in your loop should be of type `Object`, so that it is actually compatible with `String` (that's where the exception is coming from). You'll need to then verify that you've got a string in it.

Alternatively, you've got enough information there in the SQL to know that the result will really be a `List<String>`, which will in turn allow you to declare `currency` to be of type `String`. But that will involve a formally-unsafe cast; this will be a place where you know it is correct but the compiler doesn't, so you'll get a warning. It would be an appropriate place to suppress the warning (just on that one assignment/cast though; you want to try to avoid suppressing warnings because that can conceal serious problems).

Comment: And the result is definitely not a list of arrays of anything.

Comment: So is it that hibernate decides from the SQL whether it will return list of strings or list of objects based on the type of things returned ???

Comment: It knows the types. It knows how many values there are in each row. It says “one value per row; row value _is_ that value” rather than wastefully putting it inside an array of length 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong in that you are getting a list of currencies from the query. You dont need to create another array. Try this

```
List<String> currencyList = new ArrayList<String>();

//code to fetch currency
String currencySql = "select C.Currency from Currency C";
Query currencyQuery = this.em.createQuery(currencySql);

currencies = currencyQuery.getResultList();

for (String currency : currencies) {    
    currencyList.add(currency);
}
```

Comment: i am not sure what the getResultList returns. I would assume its a List. Or does it return Object Array?